# Estoy intentando graficar un circulo relacionandolo a valores ya ingresados pero no me sale

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib, spyder

Hola soy nueva programando , cree un programa para calcular el MCUV, el formulario si me funciona, pero el grafico que intento realizar no me corre, no se porque, investigue mucho para ver en que estoy fallando, pero aun asi, no encuentro como poder arreglarlo.
Estuve intentando en  matplotlib y librerias, pero sigue sin funcionarme.
este es mi codigo

```py
def SubMCUVANG():
    import tkinter as tk
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import random
    from tkinter import messagebox
    
    def calcular():
        Wo=float(datosWo.get())
        At=float(datosAt.get())
        T=float(datosT.get()) 
        R=float(datosR.get())
        Angulo=float(datosA.get())
        
        WF=Wo+At*T
        Aa=Angulo/T
        Wo=WF-At*T
        T=(WF-Wo)/At
        
        print(WF,Angulo,T,Aa,R)
        
        etiquetaSalida.configure(text ="WF:  {:} ".format(WF), fg="White",bg="Pink")
        etiquetaSalida1.configure(text ="Angulo: {:} ".format(Angulo), fg="White",bg="Pink")
        etiquetaSalida4.configure(text ="Tiempo: {:} ".format(T), fg="White",bg="Pink")
        etiquetaSalida5.configure(text ="α: {:} ".format(Aa), fg="White",bg="Pink")
        etiquetaSalida6.configure(text ="R: {:} ".format(R), fg="White",bg="Pink")
                
    def button_get():
        
        global Aa,R,T,At,Angulo    
        try:
            Aa=float(datosAangular.get())
            T=float(datosT.get())
            R=float(datosR.get())
            Angulo=float(datosA.get())
        except:
            Aa=0
            T=0
            R=0
            Angulo=0
                
        ####Evaluacion de valores Aa, T,R, Angulo #######
        if R==0 or Angulo==0:
            messagebox.showwarning("Advertencia", "Los valores deben ser diferentes de 0 ")
        else:
               from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
            
            
        num_segmentos = 20
        rad = int(datosR.get())
        cx = 2
        cy = 0
            
        angulo = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_segmentos+1)
        x = rad * np.cos(datosA.get()) + cx
        y = rad * np.sin(angulo) + cy
            
        plt.plot(x, y, color="red", markersize=1)
        #plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
            
        plt.title("Grafica del MCUV para datos Angulares")
        plt.xlabel("X")
        plt.ylabel("Y")
        plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
                    
                   
            
                    
        print(Aa,T,R,x,y,angulo,Aa,T)
```

intente llamar a la funcion de introducir datos con un .get() para relacionar los datos de ingreso del formulario con el grafico que es un circulo pero aun asi no me funciona
tambien le asigne variables y botones

```py
    botoncalc = tk.Button(text="graficar",font=("Calibri",14), command=button_get)
    botoncalc.grid(row=20,column=0)
```

y asimismo datos de entrada

```py
    #aca en tklabel se encuentran los DATOS DE ENTRADA
    
    datosWo = tk.Entry(font=('Calibri', 14), width=4) 
    datosWo.grid(row=3, column=1)
    datosT = tk.Entry(font=('Calibri', 14), width=4)
    datosT.grid(row=4, column=1)
    datosA = tk.Entry(font=('Calibri', 14), width=4)
    datosA.grid(row=5, column=1)
    datosR = tk.Entry(font=('Calibri', 14), width=4)
    datosR.grid(row=6, column=1)
    datosAt = tk.Entry(font=('Calibri', 14), width=4)
    datosAt.grid(row=7, column=1)
    datosWF = tk.Entry(font=('Calibri', 14), width=4)
    datosWF.grid(row=9, column=1)
    datosAangular = tk.Entry(font=('Calibri', 14), width=4)
    datosAangular.grid(row=10, column=1)
```

y datos de salida

Comment: No puedo replicar el problema en mi pc. Podrías proporcionar un [emcv](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Entendí que tu problema es hacer el gráfico, no mostrarlo en la ventana, si es así te dejo una función que lo genera:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def grafico_movimiento_circular(angulo, velocidad, radio):
    # Datos para el gráfico
    t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    x = radio * np.cos(t)
    y = radio * np.sin(t)

    # Creación del gráfico
    plt.plot(x, y)

    # Agregar la flecha en un punto tangencial
    plt.annotate('', xy=(np.cos(angulo), np.sin(angulo)), xytext=(np.cos(angulo + velocidad), np.sin(angulo + velocidad)), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='r', shrink=0))

    # Mostrar el gráfico
    plt.show()

grafico_movimiento_circular(np.pi/4, np.pi/10, 1) #Números al azar
```

Este ejemplo dibuja un gráfico con una flecha que se encuentra en el ángulo 45 grados, tiene una velocidad angular de 0.1 radianes por unidad de tiempo y se dibuja en un círculo de radio 1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]